# Select all components of certain type in the children Game Objects

Tags: unity

I would like to set programatically the material on a Game Object. The problem is that it has several Child Objects, which many have their own sprite.

I came up with this...

```
    foreach(Transform child in enemy.transform) {

        SpriteRenderer _spriteRenderer = child.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

        if (_spriteRenderer) {
            _spriteRenderer.material = ...;
        }

    }
```

...which works, but it is not very pretty. Is there a better way to do this?

**Update:** I know about `GetComponentsInChildren` but I need to also get the GameObject that are disabled

Answer (score 3):

See the documentation for [`GetComponentsInChildren`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentsInChildren.html):

`public Component[] GetComponentsInChildren(Type type, bool includeInactive = false);`

This states you can use the boolean `includeInactive` in `GetComponentsInChildren` to also get the inactive components. This way you can grab all the transforms. Even inactive ones. So you would probably want to do this:

```
//Create an array of SpriteRenderers
SpriteRenderer[] _spriteRenderers;
void Start ()
{
  _spriteRenderers = transform.GetComponentsInChildren<SpriteRenderer>(true); //This returns an Array
   //Change the material on all the Sprite Renderers.
   for (int i = 0; i < _spriteRenderers.Length; i++)
   {
     _spriteRenderers[i].material = ...;
   }
}
```